# How to list all current ansible inventory group list

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have ansible inventory look like this

```
all:
  children:
    environment_A:
      children:
        linux:
          children:
            functionA:
              hosts:
                hosts1
                hosts2
        windows:
            children
                functionC:
                 hosts:
                 host 5
```

how can i get a group result as follows:

```
funtionA
functionC
```

Comment: Fix the inventory's syntax and test it! `ansible-inventory -i hosts --list`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/inventory_hostnames.html):

```yaml
  - name: show all the hosts matching the pattern
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_inventory_hostnames:
      - all
```

Comment: The question asked how to list child groups of parent groups, not how to list hosts within a group

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How can i get a group result as follows [funtionA,functionC]?"*

A: You can't. Ansible doesn't keep the groups' structure. Only flat lists are available. This doesn't provide enough information to restore the groups' structure. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: groups
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: group_names
```

will display the dictionary of all groups

```yaml
ok: [host5] => {
    "groups": {
        "all": [
            "host5",
            "hosts1 hosts2"
        ],
        "environment_A": [
            "host5",
            "hosts1 hosts2"
        ],
        "functionA": [
            "hosts1 hosts2"
        ],
        "functionC": [
            "host5"
        ],
        "linux": [
            "hosts1 hosts2"
        ],
        "ungrouped": [],
        "windows": [
            "host5"
        ]
    }
}
```

and the next debug will display the lists of all groups the host is a member of

```yaml
ok: [hosts1 hosts2] => {
    "group_names": [
        "environment_A",
        "functionA",
        "linux"
    ]
}
ok: [host5] => {
    "group_names": [
        "environment_A",
        "functionC",
        "windows"
    ]
}
```

From this data, it's not possible to restore the groups' structure unambiguously. For example, the inventory below gives the same results

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
all:
  children:
    environment_A:
      children:
        functionA:
          children:
            linux:
              hosts:
                hosts1
                hosts2
        functionC:
          children:
            windows:
              hosts:
                host5
```

---

> Q: *"How to list all current ansible inventory group list?"*

A: This (the title) is a different question. The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups.keys()|list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": [
        "all",
        "ungrouped",
        "environment_A",
        "linux",
        "functionA",
        "windows",
        "functionC"
    ]
```